# Change css background color of body, everytime button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I would like my webpage background color to change between a few colors (possibly more than I have already input here) every time a button is clicked. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var colors = ["rgba(86,175,99,0.6)", "rgba(86,175,222,0.6)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"];
var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

jQuery(".rotator").click(function () {
    jQuery('body').css("background", randomColor);
});
```

It seems the code will not repeat itself. I am stuck as to how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Add randomColor in `click()`

Answer (score 1):

Add the code inside the function. The change colour is **executed only once!**

```js
colors = ["rgba(86,175,99,0.6)", "rgba(86,175,222,0.6)",     jQuery(".rotator").click(function() {
"rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"];
  randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  jQuery('body').css("background", randomColor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="rotator" href="#">Change</a>
```

Comment: Why you need `colors` to define again on `click`?

Comment: @Tushar I just copied buddy!

Comment: No. Take the `colors` out of the `click` handler

Comment: it was a joke @PraveenKumar :L

Answer (score 1):

Your random color generation execute only once because you declare the variable outiside of the click event. Generate your random color inside click event.

```
jQuery(".rotator").click(function() {
        var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        jQuery('body').css("background", randomColor);
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6dv76zx/)

Comment: @downvoter - Care to comment. What i am missing here I am also willing to learn

Answer (score 0):

Put the random colour inside your click function so it creates a random colour every time

```
var colors = ["rgba(86,175,99,0.6)", "rgba(86,175,222,0.6)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"];


    jQuery(".rotator").click(function() {

var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        jQuery('body').css("background", randomColor);
    });
```

Your first code created the random colour only once, if you put it inside the click function it creates a random colour everytime :)

Answer (score 0):

you can move randomColor function into click function

```
jQuery(".rotator").click(function() {
    jQuery('body').css("background", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});
```